# Flurry Events Counted Wrong?

Tags: android, implementation, flurry

In essence, Flurry's dashboard only shows a small amount of the event my app requests to log.
I have created a test application that has a button that calls

```
FlurryAgent.logEvent("Event Log Requested.");
```

I have ran the tester app 5 times (2 times while connected to a wifi network, then i turned network connectivity off (no 3g/no 4g/no wifi), generated one logEvent, turned wifi on, generated 2 more events).

In the dashboard, more than 24 hours later i can only see this event logged 2 times.

I expected 4 or 5 logs (depending on whether Flurry is counting the offline event).

Am I missing something? Am I reading wrong? Are events connected under certain circumstances?

Implementation:

1) SDK added to project.

2)

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, FLURRY_KEY);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
}
```

3)

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        FlurryAgent.logEvent("Event Log Requested.");
    }
});
```

P.s.,
I'm using Flurry analytics SDK v3.2.2.